# Terminal Remove Lines From SQL File and Last Line Comma

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, terminal, grep

I am attempting to import an SQL file into a database, but have had issues with CONTRAINTS due to copies of the tables already in the database. After adding 'SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;' to the database did not work I have resorted to modifying the file to remove all lines beginning 'CONSTRAINT'. This was successful with this command:

```
grep -v '^  CONSTRAINT' ~/Data.sql > ~/NewData.sql
```

However I also need to remove the comma from the end of the previous line for the syntax to be correct. Battling to achieve this, so any help is welcome :)

Here is a snippet from the file:

```
UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
KEY `classification_id` (`classification_id`),
CONSTRAINT `BodyStyle_Classification` FOREIGN KEY (`classification_id`) REFERENCES `classifications` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=29 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

Comment: You want to set foreign keys off as follows unless you have a typo above: SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo, set to 0 at start of file and 1 at end. But still fails to import the file because of the constraint.

Comment: You mentioned you have duplicates.   How are you doing your inserts?  Are you doing inserts like 'insert ignore...'?  What is the exact error message you are getting?